# how to best cannibalize a laptop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, windows-vista, readyboost

My old vista laptop is on it's last legs and I was wondering what the most efficient way of repurposing it would be. i have no need for a server and was mainly looking to see if i can jury rig Ready Boost it straight into my W7 desktop.

laptop is an 07 vista
Dell Inspiron 1545
Pentium dual core t3400
3gb ram

desktop is a 2012 win7
HP P7-1234
AMD ag-3650 apu
8gb ram

Comment: Considering the CPU, and RAM cannot be used in a desktop there isn't much of anything you can remove from a laptop and use in another machine.  Furthermore because of the age of the memory its basically worthless in modern systems.

Comment: Andrew, you wrote "see if i can jury Ready Boost it straight into my" <-- what on earth does 'jury ready boost it straight into my' mean?

Comment: meant jury rig. editing

Comment: @Ramhound The Screen of a Dell laptop can be moved and connected to a desktop with an inexpensive adaptor. And obviously the hard drive with an inexpensive adaptor. Maybe other parts, and there may be ways to 'repurpose' it without moving parts out.

Comment: The hard drive will pretty much slot in electrically, and may need a physical adaptor for 2.5 inch drives

Comment: I don't know it it's possible, but my first thought would be: ditch Vista for ubuntu server, create a ramfs that's 2.5 gigabytes, share the ramfs folder over a lan cable to the desktop, put a vhd file in the folder, mount the vhd file, and put a pagefile on it. This would give you a 2.5gb pagefile IN RAM that's only bottlenecks would be the network cable (1gbs?), and files-within-files-writing.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

- sell it before similar laptop prices on ebay drop below 100-200$
- sell it before it fall apart into pieces (I had few Dell laptops and all of them had bad chassis, bad hinges, touchpads going crazy after few years of use etc.)
- give it to your parents or someone else
- "laptop crash test" youtube video ;)

If your hinges or chassis is already disintegrated and you have some manual skills - disassemble it and make:

- online tv in the kitchen
- photo frame on wall

Without disassembling:

- video recorder with network camera
- file server (you don't want that)

Comment: the screen cracked so i hooked it up to a crt, keyboard, mouse and speakers. it's essentially a desktop tower that i have to open to turn on and worry about heat all the time

Answer (score 1):

Thats not what readyboost does - readyboost uses *local* storage, specifically USB or flash based storage as disk cache. You'd need a system that supports target mode to do this, and outside some apple laptops (that did this over firewire, and I think thunderbold), this simply does not exist.

As for salvage not terribly much. The Laptop screen is connected directly to the motherboard (though, you can get kits that convert it to a HDMI/VGA/composite screen online). The ram is likely DDR2 SODIMM, so its both the wrong type and form factor - a system from 2012 would use ddr3, and a desktop would use a DIMM. The hard drive, at least can be repurposed (though the utility of this is questionable - its probably smaller than contemporary drives, and its closer to its eventual death by bell curve).

Your PC has a mini pci-e wireless card already (and this is probably better than what your laptop has, unless you want dual band, and your laptop supports that).

Quite frankly, laptops are wonderful systems to repurpose, and terrible systems to salvage from.

Comment: no doubt one can but i'm curious, perhaps you can suggest some ways one can / you might repurpose a laptop - without salvaging parts from it?

Comment: I used to run one as a server, or a spare laptop. Some people convert them to picture frames. http://lifehacker.com/top-10-ways-to-repurpose-your-old-laptop-1522986846 has a nice list of stuff you can do, some of which I have done, or have considered in the past.